# How do I get a unique identifier string for each class instance?

Tags: ios, swift

Inside init, I need to set a unique identifier for the class instance -- one that will not be reused by any other instances or classes.

Is there some sort of internal identifier? If not, how can I generate one that doesn't collide?

Comment: I am curious to know for what purpose you need an identifier ?

Comment: How about a global, incremental integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For NSObject-derived objects, you don't need any such thing - its memory address, which is easy to obtain, *is* unique.

For other types of object, you can use the NSUUID class to give you a guaranteed unique ID.

Comment: Hi @matt: since a memory address can be reused (once the object is released) this requirement `one that will not be reused by any other instances or classes` is not guaranteed.

Comment: Oooh. Well, @appzYourLife, if his requirements are really that stringent, then the NSUUID-generated GUID seems like the simplest way. This is, after all, what it's for. On the other hand, this whole requirement seems like a Bad Smell; one would like to know more about what's _really_ going on here.

Comment: Or maybe I just misinterpreted the original question.

Answer (score -1):

Use a GUID with a combination of a timestamp. You can also simply use a GUID if you want too.